# Mocking Map parameter in Spock Framework Java test

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I am having difficulty in getting a test to work using Spock Framework in a Java project. I have the following:

```
 - Person.class 
 - Attribute.class
```

I have a service class which is being mocked in my test. The method I am trying to mock has the following signature:

```
serviceClass.call(Map<Person, List<Attribute>> map)
```

When I mock it purely using wildcards like:

```
serviceClass.call(_) >> MockReturnObject
```

Everything works as expected. The call in the service class will return the MockReturnObject.

However, for my specific case I need to specify the Person object I am passing in and assign it a specific MockReturnObject. Like:

```
serviceClass.call([(PersonA):_)]) >> MockReturnObjectA
```

or

```
def listWildcard = _
serviceClass.call(Map.of(PersonA, listWildcard)) >> MockReturnObjectA
```

Neither of these approaches work and the call ends up returning null instead of MockReturnObjectA (I assume it is because it is failing to match the arguments). I am unfortunately not too experienced with Spock and my attempt to search through documentation on handling Maps in this scenario has not come up fruitful. I would appreciate anyone able to offer any guidance.

I don't think it makes a difference but PersonA is passed in to an entry method in the serviceClass in a list like;

```
List<Attribute> list = getAttributeList() 

entryClass.process(List<Person> personList) {
        personList.forEach(person -> serviceClass.call(Map.of(person, list))
   }
```

So in my tests, the "when" is:

```
entryClass.process([PersonA, PersonB, PersonC])
```

With all 3 being Mock(Person.class) with their own behaviours.

Comment: Unfortunately not, this returns: 
Groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.call() is applicable for argument types: (org.spockframework.lang.Wildcard, org.spockframework.lang.Wildcard) values: [[*_], [*_]]

I remove the "as Person" from the end and it goes back to working but obviously then I cannot vary the response based on what I pass into call().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an object as parameter Spock will use Groovy equality to compare the argument. However, if it is too complicated to construct the reference object, you can use [code argument constraints](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_argument_constraints) instead to programmatically check the actual argument.

```
serviceClass.call({ it[PersonA] == attributeList }) >> MockReturnObject
```

As you've shared very little code this is the best example I can give.

Comment: This is a very suitable alternative for my use case. I can verify the map argument contains a particular key and provide the corresponding mock response. Thank you very much for your insight.